# Adding a closed unbounded set containing of only limit ordinals with a special property

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, forcing

The following theorem and proof are in **Applications of the proper forcing axiom**, the Baumgartner's paper in the book *Handbook of Set-theoretic topology*.

$3.6$
***THEOREM***. Assume PFA. Suppose that for each $\alpha < \omega_1$ a set $S_\alpha \subseteq \omega_1$ is given such that, for every limit ordinal $\beta < \omega_1$, $S_{\alpha} \cap \beta$ has ordertype $< \beta$. Then there is a closed unbounded set $C$ such that $ \forall \alpha < \omega_1\ C \cap S_{\alpha}$ is finite.

***PROOF***. Let $P$ consist of all $p$ for which there is a closed unbounded set $C \subseteq \omega_1$ containing only limit ordinals so that $p$ is a finite subset of the enumerating function of $C$. Let $Q$ be the set of all pairs $(p, x)$, where $p \in P$ and $x \in [\omega_1]^{<\omega}$. Let $(p_1, x_1) \leq (p_2, x_2)$ iff $ p_1 \supseteq p_2, \ x_1 \supseteq x_2$ and $\forall \alpha \in x_2 \ \text{range}(p_1 - p_2) \cap S_\alpha =0$. Now force with $Q$.

As usual we have to start by proving that $\forall \alpha < \omega_1$ the set $D_\alpha =\{ (p, x) \in Q : \alpha \in dom(p)\}$ is dense in $Q$.

For $D_0$ let we choose $(p, x) \in Q$ such that $\alpha_0 \in x,\ \omega \in S_{\alpha_0},\ p=\{(1, \omega . 2)\}$. For each $p' \supseteq p$ such that $0 \in dom(p')$ and every $x'\supseteq x,\ \omega \in \text{range}(p' - p) \cap S_{\alpha_0}$. Thus $(p', x') \nleq (p,x)$.

This counterexample shows $D_0$ isn't dense. Do we not need density? Or should we add something to the terms and definitions?

Comment: My supervisor believes that the idea should be that there is a lot of space between $f(\alpha)$ and $f(\alpha + 1)$. For example, maybe there are $\alpha + 1$ many limit ordinals or maybe more, something like this might work. Given a condition $(p, x)$ as in paper, if $f$  is the witness for $p (p \subseteq f)$ also require that if $\alpha+1$ is in $dom(f)-dom(p)$, then there are infinitely many limit ordinals between $f(\alpha)$ and $f(\alpha+1)$. This may not work, but it may give you an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe the following idea works: Given a condition as above, also require the following:

(1) for each $\alpha, f(\alpha)$ is indecomposable,

(2) suppose $dom(p)=\{\beta_0 < \beta_1 < \cdots < \beta_n\}$. Then there exists a closed subset $C$ of $f(\beta_n)$ of order type $\beta_n$ such that $C \cap \bigcup_{\gamma \in x}S_\gamma \subseteq range(p)$, for each $i$, $C \cap f(\beta_i)$ has order type $\beta_i.$ Furthermore, if $\beta_i$ is limit, then $C \cap f(\beta_i)$ is unbounded in $ f(\beta_i)$.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Mohammad-Golshani
It seems to be working properly